# javascript function works with after load changes

Tags: javascript, html

i have a javascript scroll function and it will detect elements with section class and add them to fullpage scroll. at first i have only 2 elements with section class but after clicking on a button jQuery add a new div with section class now i should have 3 fullpage instead of 2. here is the structure of my code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Full scroll main function
     */
    var fullScroll = function (params) {
        /**
         * Main div
         * @type {Object}
         */
        var main = document.getElementById(params.mainElement);

        /**
         * Sections divclass
         * @type {Array}
         */
        var sections = main.getElementsByClassName('section');

        /**
         * Full page scroll configurations
         * @type {Object}
         */
        var defaults = {
            container: main,
            sections: sections,
            animateTime: params.animateTime || 0.7,
            animateFunction: params.animateFunction || 'ease',
            maxPosition: sections.length - 1,
            currentPosition: 0,
            displayDots: typeof params.displayDots != 'undefined' ? params.displayDots : true,
            dotsPosition: params.dotsPosition || 'left'
        };

        this.defaults = defaults;
        /**
         * Init build
         */
        this.init();
    };

    /**
     * Init plugin
     */
    fullScroll.prototype.init = function () {
        this.buildPublicFunctions()
            .buildSections()
            .buildDots()
            .addEvents();

        var anchor = location.hash.replace('#', '').split('/')[0];
        location.hash = 0;
        this.changeCurrentPosition(anchor);
        this.registerIeTags();
    };

    /**
     * Build sections
     * @return {Object} this(fullScroll)
     */
    fullScroll.prototype.buildSections = function () {
        var sections = this.defaults.sections;
        for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            sections[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Build dots navigation
     * @return {Object} this (fullScroll)
     */
    fullScroll.prototype.buildDots = function () {
        this.ul = document.createElement('ul');

        this.ul.className = this.updateClass(1, 'dots', this.ul.className);
        this.ul.className = this.updateClass(1, this.defaults.dotsPosition == 'right' ? 'dots-right' : 'dots-left', this.ul.className);

        var _self = this;
        var sections = this.defaults.sections;

        for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement('a');

            a.setAttribute('href', '#' + i);
            li.appendChild(a);
            _self.ul.appendChild(li);
        }

        this.ul.childNodes[0].firstChild.className = this.updateClass(1, 'active', this.ul.childNodes[0].firstChild.className);

        if (this.defaults.displayDots) {
            document.body.appendChild(this.ul);
        }

        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Add Events
     * @return {Object} this(fullScroll)
     */
    fullScroll.prototype.addEvents = function () {

        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
            document.addEventListener('wheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
            document.addEventListener('keyup', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
            document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchStart, false);
            document.addEventListener('touchend', this.touchEnd, false);
            window.addEventListener("hashchange", this.hashChange, false);

            /**
             * Enable scroll if decive don't have touch support
             */
            if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                if (!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
                    document.body.style = "overflow: scroll;";
                    document.documentElement.style = "overflow: scroll;";
                }
            }

        } else {
            document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
            document.attachEvent('onkeyup', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
        }

        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Build public functions
     * @return {[type]} [description]
     */
    fullScroll.prototype.buildPublicFunctions = function () {
        var mTouchStart = 0;
        var mTouchEnd = 0;
        var _self = this;

        this.mouseWheelAndKey = function (event) {
            if (event.deltaY > 0 || event.keyCode == 40) {
                _self.defaults.currentPosition++;
                _self.changeCurrentPosition(_self.defaults.currentPosition);
            } else if (event.deltaY < 0 || event.keyCode == 38) {
                _self.defaults.currentPosition--;
                _self.changeCurrentPosition(_self.defaults.currentPosition);
            }
            _self.removeEvents();
        };

        this.touchStart = function (event) {
            mTouchStart = parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].clientY);
            mTouchEnd = 0;
        };

        this.touchEnd = function (event) {
            mTouchEnd = parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].clientY);
            if (mTouchEnd - mTouchStart > 100 || mTouchStart - mTouchEnd > 100) {
                if (mTouchEnd > mTouchStart) {
                    _self.defaults.currentPosition--;
                } else {
                    _self.defaults.currentPosition++;
                }
                _self.changeCurrentPosition(_self.defaults.currentPosition);
            }
        };

        this.hashChange = function (event) {
            if (location) {
                var anchor = location.hash.replace('#', '').split('/')[0];
                if (anchor !== "") {
                    if (anchor < 0) {
                        _self.changeCurrentPosition(0);
                    } else if (anchor > _self.defaults.maxPosition) {
                        _self.changeCurrentPosition(_self.defaults.maxPosition);
                    } else {
                        _self.defaults.currentPosition = anchor;
                        _self.animateScroll();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        this.removeEvents = function () {
            if (document.addEventListener) {
                document.removeEventListener('mousewheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
                document.removeEventListener('wheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
                document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
                document.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.touchStart, false);
                document.removeEventListener('touchend', this.touchEnd, false);

            } else {
                document.detachEvent('onmousewheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
                document.detachEvent('onkeyup', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
            }

            setTimeout(function () {
                _self.addEvents();
            }, 600);
        };

        this.animateScroll = function () {
            var animateTime = this.defaults.animateTime;
            var animateFunction = this.defaults.animateFunction;
            var position = this.defaults.currentPosition * 100;

            this.defaults.container.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(-' + position + 'vh)';
            this.defaults.container.style.mozTransform = 'translateY(-' + position + 'vh)';
            this.defaults.container.style.msTransform = 'translateY(-' + position + 'vh)';
            this.defaults.container.style.transform = 'translateY(-' + position + 'vh)';
            this.defaults.container.style.webkitTransition = 'all ' + animateTime + 's ' + animateFunction;
            this.defaults.container.style.mozTransition = 'all ' + animateTime + 's ' + animateFunction;
            this.defaults.container.style.msTransition = 'all ' + animateTime + 's ' + animateFunction;
            this.defaults.container.style.transition = 'all ' + animateTime + 's ' + animateFunction;

            for (var i = 0; i < this.ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
                this.ul.childNodes[i].firstChild.className = this.updateClass(2, 'active', this.ul.childNodes[i].firstChild.className);
                if (i == this.defaults.currentPosition) {
                    this.ul.childNodes[i].firstChild.className = this.updateClass(1, 'active', this.ul.childNodes[i].firstChild.className);
                }
            }
        };

        this.changeCurrentPosition = function (position) {
            if (position !== "") {
                _self.defaults.currentPosition = position;
                location.hash = _self.defaults.currentPosition;
            }
        };

        this.registerIeTags = function () {
            document.createElement('section');
        };

        this.updateClass = function (type, newClass, currentClass) {
            if (type == 1) {
                return currentClass += ' ' + newClass;
            } else if (type == 2) {
                return currentClass.replace(newClass, '');
            }
        };

        return this;
    };
    window.fullScroll = fullScroll;
})();

scrollFunc = new fullScroll({
                mainElement: 'scrollProduct',
                displayDots: false,
                animateTime: 0.7,
                animateFunction: 'ease'
            });
```

1              
        
    
    
        
            2

Comment: I don't understand - what is the question?

Comment: Do you have  the html as well as the javascript?

Comment: @leonsegal here is html codes
<div id="main" class="scroll-container">
  <div class="section">
   <div>
    <span>1</span>    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
   <div>
    <span>2</span>    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: i want to use this scroll function after changin DOM with jQuery again

Comment: Can you make it a HTML + JS + CSS post or link a jsfiddle please